# InputPane disable hiding (Windows Phone 8.1)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing windows phone app and I need in some cases to disable the `InputPane` hiding functionality when the ui refocuses on some other elements.

Currently I am doing so by refocusing to `TextBox` - but it causes "flickering" of my keyboard, cause its hiding and reopening very quickly.

Is there any way to cancel `InputPane` hiding on Hiding event or any other way to accomplish this behavior?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you set the IsTabStop property to false on some other elements?

Comment: That works realy great! Thank you, you can also post it as an answer (cause it is). I never had in mind that this property existed and event after I saw it disn't seems to be relevant.. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set `IsTabStop` property to false on the other elements so that they wont recieve focus in UI interaction.

You can check about `IsTabStop` property here - [Control.IsTabStop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control.istabstop)